# Are there any applications that actually rotate an image?

Tags: images

I have Sketchbook Mobile, and I'll draw some image with my phone tilted on the side. Now I want the image rotated. Sketchbook Mobile doesn't have the option to rotate the actual image, and so far neither does any program that I've actually tried. They just rotate how the image is displayed but they don't modify the actual image, so when I upload it to Photobucket or something, it's 90 degrees off.

Are there any programs that *actually* rotate an image?

Comment: I was going to mention the stock Gallery app, but my guess is that it just rotates the view, and not the actual picture itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used [Photo Wonder](https://market.android.com/details?id=cn.jingling.motu.photowonder) for this on older versions of Android.

In newer versions of Android, the built-in Gallery app supports this.

Comment: Perfect! A bit heavy for just rotating an image, but it gets the job done. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

For this and all my editing needs on my phone, I use [PicsArt](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.picsart.studio).